# Signal Processing: Sample rate vs sample period

Tags: python-3.x, signals, signal-processing, sampling

Let's consider the following code:

```
f = 40;  # Hz
tmin = -0.3;
tmax = 0.3;
t, sampling_period = linspace(start=tmin, stop=tmax, num=400, retstep=True); # here I am saying split in 400 regular interval the 0.6 units of times. 

# Based on the above, I obtain the distance between two regular intervals of 0.0015 = 0.6/400 ==> 
# sample period T = 0.0015
significant_digits = 2
rounded_sampling_period = round(sampling_period, significant_digits - 
int(math.floor(math.log10(abs(sampling_period)))) - 1)
sampling_frequency = 1/rounded_sampling_period
print("sampling_period - regular intervals of T = ", sampling_period)
print("rounded_sampling_period ", rounded_sampling_period)
print("sampling_frequency or sample rate = 1/T ", sampling_frequency)
x = cos(2*pi*f*t); # signal sampling
plot(t, x)
```

I am getting as results:

```
sampling_period - regular intervals of T =  0.0015037593984962405
rounded_sampling_period  0.0015
sampling_frequency  666.6666666666666
```

What is wrong in trying to understand the difference between Sample rate vs sample period? 666.666 does not make sense?

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing two different concepts, the signal frequency/period and the sample frequency/period.

The signal frequency/period is the interval in which the signal repeat itself.

The sample frequency/period is the distance between samples (between points in an array in this case)

So that's why you are getting 666.66, because your signal is sampled between 400 data points over a period of time of 0.6 seconds (0.3 -(-0.3)), and thats results in 666.66

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to simulate with python code the difference between signal frequency/period and sample frequency/period explicitly?

Comment: Sure, in this case the signal frequency is user defined, it's 40Hz. For the Sample frequency you could do `sample_freq=n_samples/(tmax-tmin)` with n_samples being the number supplied in the num argument of linsapce. Then the period is just `sample_preiod=1/sample_freq`

Comment: Thank you. But How what you are suggesting is different from the above? "sample_freq=n_samples/(tmax-tmin)" would produce 666.66. What I am trying to clarify is something like this: Code that explain signal frequence/period and code that explian sample frequence/period....thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this image will visualize the concept better 

[link](https://images.app.goo.gl/BkPk3YhuuXLb7NSf6)

The sampling interval is the "space" between each sample, and the signal interval is the period of the signal ( where f(t) = f(t+kT) )
In this case, you are hardcoding the signal frequency ( a 40Hz sine wave) and the sample rate (generated by the 400 samples set in linspaces distributed in the time axis from t=-0.3 to t=0.3)